# The action of free group on line

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, free-groups

Let $G$ be a free group, if the action of $G$ on $\mathbb{R}$ is free, does it imply that $G$ is abelian?

Comment: I think this should come down mostly to definitions.

Comment: "the" action of $G$ on $\mathbb R$? Is there supposed to be a fixed action here? Are there any restrictions on this action in terms of the structure of $G$ and $\mathbb R$?

Answer (score 3):

Hölder has proved that any group $G$ which acts freely on the real line by homeomorphisms is abelian.